# How to set/read the parent ${project.version} refernce from external properties file in my POM XML

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Can anyone please  help on this, if this is feasible  , I am trying to fetch the main `${project.version}` value form the external  property file , Is this possible to load if yes can you please suggest

here is one of the example,
version. Properties contains this value 
`theme.version=1.1.1-snapshot`

My Pom.xml cantains the references of this version.

```
<parent><groupId>--</groupId>
<artifactId>theme</artifactId>
<version>${theme.version}</version></parent>
```

If I do `mvn clean install` I want my repository war file to be updated with the `theme.version` as `1.1.1-snapshot`. Basically I meant not to update my POM.xml with any versions numbers I want it to load everything from the properties file always

Comment: Which maven version do you use?

Comment: Starting with Maven 3.2.1 you can [define version as a property](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html) like `${revision}`, `${changelist}`, and `${sha1}`. With Maven 3.1.X or less you can't define the versions like this and apart from that it does not really make sense, cause you can use versions-maven-plugin or maven-release-plugin to handle this.